# How can i catch the System OS Notification in iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to catch System OS notifications, but cannot find any relative code to help me with it. Is there any default system calls to accomplish this programatically without using any third party library?

Comment: What system notifications do you mean?

Comment: I mean OS Default Notification

Comment: That doesn't clarify your question at all. What do you mean by OS Default Notification? Be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the `NSNotificationCenter`. That's probably what you're looking for. I suggest searching on that in the Xcode docs.

If that's not what you're looking for then you are going to have to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your answer